# syncing up new clients with socket.io

Tags: javascript, websocket, ecmascript-6, socket.io

wasn't really sure of the terminology for this so sorry for any confusion. basically i have an app that when the display button is clicked, it adds an image to the dom and all clients can see this image being added in real time. my question is about new clients connecting to the server. lets say i added 4 images. the 4 images show up fine. but, if a new client connects after these images are added, they see no images displayed on the page. so if i clicked display button and added 1 more image, 1 client now sees 5 images, while the new client only sees 1 image. how can i get all clients to see the same thing, regardless of when they connected to the server? the code below is not broken and just shows the basic functionality of my app, i'm just not sure where to start or what to add.

server

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');


// app set up
const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
// const  = new socket(server);
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// static files
app.use(express.static('app'));

// socket setup & pass SERVER
const io = new socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('made connection!!!');
    // events

    socket.on('test', function(data){
        console.log('SERVER ' + data.image);
        io.sockets.emit('test', data);
    });

});

io.on('connect_error', function(){
    console.log('fail');
});


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server running....');
});
```

client

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import SaveInput from './SaveInput';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

// make connection
const socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');


class Display extends SaveInput {

  constructor(){


    this.pGrid = $('.pic-grid-container');
    this.display = $('#btn-display');
    this.buttons();

  }

  buttons (){

    // click buttons
    this.display.click(this.displayEls.bind(this));


  }

  //display images 
  displayEls() {
    let img = './assets/images/baseball/team0.jpg';
    let $picContainer = $('<div class="picture-frame"></div>');
    let  $newImg = $('<img>');

    // EMIT
    socket.emit('test', {
      image: img
    });

    // listen
    socket.on('test', function(data) {
        let that = this;
        let foo = data.image.toString();

        $newImg.attr('src', foo);
        $newImg.appendTo($picContainer);
        that.pGrid.append($picContainer);
    });


  }

}

export default Display;
```

Answer (score 2):

When the client connects to the server, you can send them a message containing the initial state of the system. This can be done in the `io.on('connection' ...)` event handler.

For this to work though, you need to keep track of the state on the server too in addition to the clients.

Comment: this makes sense. my initial thought is to duplicate the code on the server and store it and wait for the connection to display it. are there any examples you know of that may show how to do this efficiently?